# grep logs between two dates and contain specific string in linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have log file like this

```
Oct 11 2022 17:00:00 AriaDezh filterlog: 1054<1>,82,,,0,lo0,match,pass,in,4,0x0,,64,0,0,DF,6,tcp,60,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,50191,14382,0,S,1420028472,,65228,,mss;nop;wscale;sackOK;TS 

Oct 12 2022 17:00:00 AriaDezh filterlog: 1055<1>,83,,,0,lo0,match,pass,out,4,0x0,,64,0,0,DF,6,tcp,60,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,50191,14382,0,S,1420028472,,65228,,mss;nop;wscale;sackOK;TS

Oct 13 2022 17:00:00 AriaDezh filterlog: 1055<1>,83,,,0,lo0,match,pass,out,4,0x0,,64,0,0,DF,6,tcp,60,192.168.1.1,127.0.0.1,50191,14382,0,S,1420028472,,65228,,mss;nop;wscale;sackOK;TS

Oct 14 2022 17:00:00 AriaDezh filterlog: 1055<1>,83,,,0,lo0,match,pass,out,4,0x0,,64,0,0,DF,6,tcp,60,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,50191,14382,0,S,1420028472,,65228,,mss;nop;wscale;sackOK;TS
```

I want dateTimes compared and get logs that are between **two dateTimes** and contain 192.168.1.1

```
grep -F /2022-10-12T16:00:00/ /2022-10-13T18:00:00/ '192.168.1.1'
```

the expected result would be like that

```
Oct 13 2022 17:00:00 AriaDezh filterlog: 1055<1>,83,,,0,lo0,match,pass,out,4,0x0,,64,0,0,DF,6,tcp,60,192.168.1.1,127.0.0.1,50191,14382,0,S,1420028472,,65228,,mss;nop;wscale;sackOK;TS
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: it would help if you provided more input; in particular ... log entries with different date/time stamps, some within the range you're looking for, some outside the range you're looking for; then we need an example of the `two dates` you're looking for (also, do you know for a fact the two dates will find exact matches in the file or will we need to perform date/time comparisons?); a sample of the `string` your looking for; and lastly, the expected output (corresponding to the sample input); what other code have you tried that attempts to match the date/time stamps?

Comment: @markp-fuso I added some more details

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the [mktime() function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html).

```
awk -v start='2022 10 12 16 00 00' -v end='2022 10 13 18 00 00' '
function month2num(mon ){
     return sprintf("%02d", (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", mon)+2)/3)
 }

{ dt=$3" "month2num($1)" "$2" "$4; gsub(/:/," ", dt) }

mktime(dt)>=mktime(start) && mktime(dt)<=mktime(end) && /192\.168\.1\.1/' infile
```